# How can I convert between RGB565 and RGB24 image formats in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, image-manipulation, image-formats

I am getting an RGB matrix from a microprocessor that outputs an image in RGB565 format. I want to read this into MATLAB, convert it to RGB24 format, and output the image. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried reading your RGB565 image into MATLAB using [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html)? What information is listed for `X` and `map` when you do this?: `[X,map] = imread('your_file.bmp'); whos`

Comment: there is no file.bmp. This is raw RGB values coming from a uP

Comment: Okay, so how are you getting these values into MATLAB? If you've already managed to put them in a variable, what is that variables type? Is it uint16?

Comment: What exactly is a uP, and how does it communicate with Matlab?

Comment: @Jonas: I believe it means "microprocessor".

Comment: yes I do sorry. A microprocessor outputs to a text file RGB565 values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first have to read your data from the text file into a matrix in MATLAB. Since I don't know what format your text file is in, I can only suggest that you will probably need to use the function [`fscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) to read in all of your values (probably of type [`uint16`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html)), then you will likely have to reshape the values into an N-by-M image matrix using the function [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

Let's assume you've done all that, and you now have an N-by-M matrix `img` of unsigned 16-bit integers. First, you can use the function [`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html) to extract the bits for the red, green, and blue components, whose positions in the 16-bit integer are illustrated here:

[image]

Next, you can use the function [`bitshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html) and multiplication by a scale factor to scale the red, green, and blue values to a range of 0 to 255, then convert them to an unsigned 8-bit integer using the function [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html). This will give you three color component matrices the same size as `img`:

```
imgR = uint8((255/31).*bitshift(bitand(img, 63488), -11));  % Red component
imgG = uint8((255/63).*bitshift(bitand(img, 2016), -5));    % Green component
imgB = uint8((255/31).*bitand(img, 31));                    % Blue component
```

Now you can use the function [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to put the three color components into an N-by-M-by-3 RGB image matrix, then save the image to an RGB24 bitmap file using the function [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html):

```
imgRGB = cat(3, imgR, imgG, imgB);  % Concatenate along the third dimension
imwrite(imgRGB, 'myImage.bmp');     % Output the image to a file
```

**EXAMPLE:**

Using a randomly generated 100-by-100 matrix of uint16 values and applying the above conversions, here are the results:

```
img = randi([0 65535], 100, 100, 'uint16');
% Perform the above conversions to get imgRGB
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(img);
title('Random uint16 image');
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(imgRGB);
title('Corresponding RGB image');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

RGB565 means 5 bit red, 6 bit green and 5 bit blue. RGB24 is made of 8 bit red, 8 bit green and 8 bit blue.

Using bitget and bitset you may convert your data.

http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html

Comment: So once I have converted it to RGB24, how can I make matlab show it as an image?